# E2040 Declaration terminated incorrectly

Tags: c++, c++builder, winscp, jedi-code-library

I am building WinSCP from source.

When compiling source, following error occurs:

```
[bcc32 Error] Jcl.cpp(9): E2040 Declaration terminated incorrectly
```

The IDE is indicating at following source.

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# include<System.hpp>
# pragma hdrstop
# pragma package(smart_init)
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Package source.
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma argsused extern " C " int _libmain(unsigned long reason)
{
  return 1;
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Could anybody please tell me what is wrong and how to correct.

Comment: The `#pragma` should be on its own line.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimPileborg, I notice that the function was mixed with #pragma..now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual WinSCP code is:

```
#pragma argsused
extern "C" int _libmain(unsigned long reason)
{
  return 1;
}
```

See [`Jcl.cpp` in WinSCP Git repository](https://github.com/winscp/winscp/blob/5.12.2/source/Jcl.cpp).

You must have corrupted the code yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Prikryl, I even did not know how the file was mistakenly corrupted. But I managed according to  Joachim Pileborg comment. :)